# SQL loop on each partition

Tags: sql

I am doing a `rank` and `partition by` on my_table and get the following table result

```
SELECT 
t.ID, t.rank, t.score1, t.score2
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY r.id ORDER BY t.rank ASC) rank
FROM my_table t
```

```
+-----+------+--------+--------+
| ID  | rank | score1 | score2 |
+-----+------+--------+--------+
| id1 | 1    | 1      | 1      |
+-----+------+--------+--------+
| id1 | 2    | 0.8    | 0      |
+-----+------+--------+--------+
| id1 | 3    | 0.7    | 0      |
+-----+------+--------+--------+
| id1 | 4    | 0.6    | 0      |
+-----+------+--------+--------+
| id2 | 1    | 1      | 1      |
+-----+------+--------+--------+
| id2 | 2    | 0.8    | 0      |
+-----+------+--------+--------+
| id2 | 3    | 0.9    | 0      |
+-----+------+--------+--------+
| id2 | 4    | 0.7    | 0      |
+-----+------+--------+--------+
| id2 | 5    | 1      | 1      |
+-----+------+--------+--------+
```

then I want to count in each partition by `ID`, if both `score1` and `score2` are in descending order. For example, for `id1`, the partition meets the requirement, while in `id2` it fails. I want to finally return a `number_of_failed_partition/number_of_total_partition` percentage. In this example, the result returned is 50%.

I am thinking of doing a for loop inside each partition, pseudocode:

```
for curRow in partition
   if nextRow.score1 > curRow.Score1 or nextRow.score2 > curRow.Score2
       failed_partition_count++
       break, proceed to next partition
```

Is there some way I can check/do for loop inside each partition in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work to do what you want.

```
WITH test as (select id, score1, score2 from my_table)
    SELECT curr.[id]
          ,curr.[rank]
          ,curr.[score1]
          ,curr.[score2]
          , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table where curr.score1 > old.score1 and curr.score2 > old.score2) as record
      FROM my_table curr
      left join test old on old.id = curr.id-1
```